# SQL concat a Column based on duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

```
Table1:
id Name
1  John
2   Bob

Table2:
id tags table1_id
1  dog      1
2  cat      1
3  tiger    2
```

When I tried this code:

```
Select Table1.*, Table2.tags FROM Table1 inner join Table2 on Table1.id = Table2.table1_id
```

This gives me

```
id Name tags
1  John dog
1  John cat
2  Bob  tiger
```

Is it possible to combine the tags to one string which makes the result into:

```
id Name tags

1  John dog,cat
2  Bob  tiger
```

Comment: similar questions asked many times on SO.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group_concat function will concatenate fields based off of a specified grouping field.

```
Select 
table1.id,
Table1.name, 
group_concat(Table2.tags) 
FROM Table1 
inner join Table2
on Table1.id = Table2.table1_id
group by table1.id, table1.name;
```

Comment: great do could we do it for mssql too?

Comment: apparently SQL server doesn't have a built in function for this like mySQL or Oracle, but there is a workaround to make it work. http://dbfriend.blogspot.com/2012/02/groupconcat-or-listagg.html